# Updating a Combobox when when a new row or edit is made to SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a SQLite database. I currently can insert, update and delete records in the database. I have a few combo boxes inside of my program are loaded with the information from my datatable. Currently, for me to get the combo boxes to refresh I must quit the program and start it again to get them to refresh.

I am trying to figure out how I can get the combobox to update once I have entered or edited a record.

The following is my code. I am only showing one combobox that I am trying to update. The comboBoxNameRetrival() is where I am using a query to load my combobox data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Baby_Tracker
{
    public partial class BabyTracker : Form
    {
        BabyEntryForm babyEntryForm = new BabyEntryForm();
        BabyUpdateForm babyUpdateForm = new BabyUpdateForm();
        BabyDeleteForm babyDeleteForm = new BabyDeleteForm();

        public BabyTracker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBoxNameRetrival();
        }


        /*
        *  Allows for the BabyEntryForm to be opened for the user to 
        *  add a new entry for a baby.
        */
        private void newBaby_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            babyEntryForm.Show();
        }


        /*
       *  Allows for the BabyUpdateForm to be opened for the user to 
       *  add a updated entry for a baby.
       */
        private void editBaby_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            babyUpdateForm.Show();
        }


        /*
        *  Calls the FirstName table from the SQLite database to be displayed inside
        *  the combob box. This is also set to refresh as a new baby is entered into the
        *  application.
        */
        public void comboBoxNameRetrival()
        {
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             string connectionString = "Data Source = BabyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;";
             using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
             {
                using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName FROM BabyList", connection))
                {
                    dt.Clear();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    babySelector_cmbo.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
                    babySelector_cmbo.DataSource = dt;
                    connection.Close();
                }
             }
          }


        /*
        *  Used for the selection of the combobox name to be changed throughout the program
        *  as needed. Also, the image for each baby is changed here where the path is called
        *  from the database to then load the image for each baby based off of the selection
        *  from the combobox
        *  
        *  Note: The heart of changing data between differenet babies.
        */
        private void babySelector_cmbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            name_lb.Text = babySelector_cmbo.GetItemText(babySelector_cmbo.SelectedItem); //loads the selected name from combobox to theis label

            string query = "SELECT BabyImagePath FROM BabyList where FirstName = '" + babySelector_cmbo.GetItemText(babySelector_cmbo.SelectedItem) + "'";
            string connectionString = "Data Source = BabyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;";
            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string result = Convert.ToString(reader["BabyImagePath"]);
                    userImage_box.Image = Image.FromFile(result);
                }
        }


        /*
         * Calls the BabyDeleteForm to allow for the user to delete an
         * baby entry.
         */
        private void deleteBaby_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            babyDeleteForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This the class where I am doing all of my updates and adding to the database. The addBabyConnection() method is where I am adding a new user. Here is where I am excepting to call the comboBoxNameRetrival() method in the previous class to update that combobox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Baby_Tracker
{
    class AddUpdateDeleteBaby 
    {

        //String declarations
        public string path;
        public string targetPath;


        /*
         * Method is using the data from the BabyEntryForm textboxes to create a new row for
         * each new baby entered. The connection and all database requires are set up here. 
         * BabyList is the table that is being used for the storage of the information.
         */
        public void addBabyConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source = BabyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;";
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            using (SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BabyList (ID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, DOB, BirthWeight, BirthLength, BirthHeadCir, BabyImagePath) VALUES (@id, @firstName, @middleName, @lastName, @DOB, @birthWeight, @birthLength, @birthHeadCir, @babyImagePath)";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", null);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", BabyEntryForm.firstName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", BabyEntryForm.middleName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", BabyEntryForm.lastName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", BabyEntryForm.dob);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthWeight", BabyEntryForm.weight);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthLength", BabyEntryForm.length);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthHeadCir", BabyEntryForm.headCir);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@babyImagePath", BabyEntryForm.imagePath);

                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                BabyTracker bt = new BabyTracker();
                bt.comboBoxNameRetrival();
            }
        }


        /* Allows for a image to be selected for the baby entry. This is called via
         * both new baby entry and also update baby entry. Only JPEG na dPNG images 
         * are accepted here. The files are then saved to a folder (BabyImages) in
         * the application.
         */
        public void babyImagePath()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            openFileDialog.Title = "Selet Baby Profile Image";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = @"C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Baby_Tracker\Baby_Tracker\BabyImages"; //save to file location
                targetPath = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName));

                File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, targetPath, true);
            }
        }


        /* Connections to the database to use the information entered from the
         * BabyUpdateForm to update the database based upon the fields that 
         * have entered data.
         */
        public void updateBaby()
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source = BabyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;";
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            using (SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE BabyList SET FirstName = @firstName, MiddleName = @middleName, LastName = @lastName, DOB = @DOB, BirthWeight = @birthWeight, BirthLength = @birthLength, BirthHeadCir = @birthHeadCir, BabyImagePath = @babyImagePath WHERE FirstName = '"+BabyUpdateForm.comboName+"'";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", BabyUpdateForm.updateFirstName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", BabyUpdateForm.updateMiddleName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", BabyUpdateForm.updateLastName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", BabyUpdateForm.updatedob);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthWeight", BabyUpdateForm.updateWeight);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthLength", BabyUpdateForm.updateLength);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthHeadCir", BabyUpdateForm.updateHeadCir);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@babyImagePath", BabyUpdateForm.updateImagePath);

                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }


        /* Connects to the database to allow for the user to delete a baby 
         * entry that they have previously made. Once a baby is deleted 
         * from the database, all data is lost on the baby and must
         * be reentered as a new baby.
         */
        public void deletebaby()
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source = BabyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;";
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            using (SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM BabyList WHERE FirstName = '" + BabyDeleteForm.comboName + "'";

                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: change `babyUpdateForm.Show();` to `babyUpdateForm.ShowDialog();comboBoxNameRetrival();`

Comment: Thank you!! That worked perfectly. I guess I was just trying to overthink it completely.

Comment: this is one of many solutions, and the one closest to your existing code.